# How to delete constructors and operators using inheritance in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have two classes, `no_copy` and `no_move` which are base classes. From which any class can derive from and hence have their constructors and operators modified.

As the name suggests, `no_copy` will literally just do the following; (commented out what it should do)

```cpp
class base : no_copy
{
    /*
       base(const base&)=delete;
       base& operator=(const base&)=delete;
    */
};
```

And the same for `no_move`,

```cpp
class base : no_move
{
    /*
       base(base&&)=delete;
       base& operator=(base&&)=delete;
    */
};
```

These classes (`no_copy` & `no_move`) make it so that the class that derives from it should not be *copyable* or *moveable*.

Right now I am just using a macro to do this;

```cpp
// For classes without a qualified name
#define __NO_COPY__(__class__) __class__::__class__(const __class__&)=delete; __class__& __class__::operator=(const __class__&)=delete;

// For classes with qualified names
#define __NO_COPY_LIB__(__qualified_name__,__class__) __qualified_name__::__class__(const __class__&)=delete; __class__& __qualified_name__::operator=(const __class__&)=delete;
```

And the same technique for not moving.

---

**EDIT:**
Examples of the macros;

suppose a class as such;

```cpp
namespace wrapper
{
   class my_class {};

   __NO_COPY__(my_class);
}
__NO_COPY_LIB__(::wrapper::my_class,my_class);
```

---

The macros work just fine, but it doesn't look pretty. Moreover they are not easy to refactor as these macros can be anywhere in the *definition* or *implementation*.

A syntax like the following would mean that all of this in right there in the definition of the class and can be changed or modified very easily;

```cpp
class base : public attributes<no_copy,no_move> {};
```

The `attributes` struct is just defined as;

```cpp
template <typename... _BCs/*Base Classes*/>
struct attibutes : public _BCs... {};
```

Now obviously the syntax of inheriting doesn't matter that much. All I want it to be able to define where the class can be copied,moved or not. Also, if there is a method other than inheritance which could work please do suggest it.

As all I am looking for is the method that is easily refactorable.

---

I have tried finding solutions online about how to overload constructors. But so far I have not found anything about deleting them and hence I am doubting if it is even possible to delete constructors or operators using inheritance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats wrong with `foo(const foo&)=delete;` (and the others)? Its a perfectly readable and clear way to make a type non-copyable

Comment: Why write `class base : public attributes<no_copy,no_move> ` when `class base : no_copy,no_move` works just fine ?

Comment: there is `boost::non_copyable` but since C++11 (which introduced `= delete`) imho it can be considered deprecated

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That definition could be anywhere (across multiple files). It is not easily refactorable

Comment: this question is missing a clear specific question. You are asking for "help", but what would be a solution seems to be only up to opinions

Comment: I dont undertand what you mean with "anywhere" or "not easily refactorable".  It cannot be anywhere, its in the class definition, I mean where else should it be?

Comment: You can mark a function as being *deleted* anywhere.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev: You can mark a function as being deleted anywhere, provided it was first declared in the class definition.  Note that doing this will confuse not only programmers but also the compiler -- type traits will still report such a class as copyable / copy assignable, movable, etc.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev: Actually, the *anywhere* is no longer true: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.def.delete#4  I'm quite sure that earlier versions of C++ did allow it though.

Comment: *"As all I am looking for is the method that is easily refactorable."* -- what sort of refactoring did you have in mind? Removing a base class looks like an easy refactor to me, but you apparently think otherwise. Please give something more concrete as the criterion.

Comment: It would be way simpler to just mark the copy constructor of your class as `delete`d instead of using a `no_copy` base class. First reason, it's simpler and clearer. Second reason, it's stronger: With the base class solution, nothing prevent you to inherit from `no_copy` and then still define a copy constructor in the derived class anyway.

Comment: @JaMiT C++20's constraints and requires-expressions, particularly in allowing constraints on non-template (special) member functions, do offer us a much easier approach for implementing _a single_ trait-based base class (if we'd like to). Whilst this was possible also pre-C++17, it required quite a lot of boilerplate (e.g. mixins).

Comment: In my experience it is in the long run better for maintainability to be explicit in each class (wrt to deleting copy/move constructors etc) then to add that by inheritance to save on a bit of typing.  Using inheritance only for code reuse is IMO not the way to go. And then add compile time (unit test) to check if your classes have the correct copy/move semantics wrt design. So is it pays to be explicit and to keep changes as local as you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Special member functions delegate to the corresponding functions of their subobjects (bases and members) and will be defaulted as deleted if that delegation finds a deleted or inaccessible function.

- https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.ctor#class.copy.ctor-10
- https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.copy.assign#7

Although you could use a non-static member for this, using a base class is better because it enables the "Empty Base Optimization", not costing anything.

```
struct no_copy
{
protected:
    no_copy() = default;
    no_copy(const no_copy&) = delete;
    no_copy& operator=(const no_copy&) = delete;
};

class important_class : no_copy {};
```

pre-C++11 version:

```
class no_copy // members default to "private"
{
    no_copy(const no_copy&); // no definition needed
    no_copy& operator=(const no_copy&); // no definition needed
protected:
    no_copy() {}
};
```

This won't stop the derived class from defining a user-provided special member that explicitly avoids calling the base class version, but if you do that it shows intent to make the derived class actually be copyable/whatever after all.

Comment: Are you taking advantage of the fact that the members of `no_copy` cannot be copied and hence the entire base class cannot be copied?

Comment: @AmritSanjeev: I think I already explained that, in the first paragraph.  The rules are https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.ctor#class.copy.ctor-10 and

Comment: It may be necessary to add a default constructor in `no_copy` otherwise `important_class` would not be constructible at all (if no base class constructor is available)

Comment: You already got my upvote but still I'm frustrated about this solution (and the question itself). It is way simpler, clearer and safer to just mark the `important_class`'s copy constructor as `delete`d (or make it `private` if pre-C++11) and get rid of both the inheritance and the `no_copy` definition. As you mentioned, nothing prevent the user to inherit from `no_copy` and still define a copy constructor in the derived class, which would be an open door to inconsistencies.

Comment: @Fareanor: This question explicitly asks for a solution using inheritance, and says nothing about preventing the user from providing a copy constructor.  The whole question is really unclear because the macros that OP says work actually are ill-formed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I completely agree with you despite... it is not my question :D

Comment: @Fareanor: oops, missed that.  It seems then that you have a different question than OP and should ask it separately, being sure to be clear about what you are looking for that the inheritance solution does not provide.  (Note that dfrib's answer is also an inheritance-based solution and can also be bypassed with an explicit user-provided function in the derived class.)

Comment: My point was that the question itself is a non-sense to me. It's more like "How to make complicated and unsafe something that is simple and safe" :)

Comment: @Fareanor: Well I do find ": no_copy" (two tokens) a lot simpler than writing out multiple deleted declarations.  And while the ability for a derived class to define a copy constructor (mutatis mutandi for move or assignment) that forgets to handle subobjects is a problem, that is really unrelated to this question -- it applies equally to classes which are copyable and moveable.

Comment: @Fareanor: Also note that the C++98/03 approach of making a private special function in the derived class is much much less safe, because it is still accessible to all other member functions of the class.  The inheritance approach was better in those versions of C++.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++20 and its new requires-expressions, this previously quite hasslesome of a task (e.g. implementing `std::optional` pre-C++20, mixins and so on) has now become quite neat, as we can conditionally delete a special member function based on traits to the common reusable `attributes` base class.

```
enum class options {
    no_default,
    no_copy,
    no_move,
};

template <options... opts>
struct attributes {
 protected:
    attributes() requires contains_v<options::no_default, opts...>               = delete;
    attributes() requires(!contains_v<options::no_default, opts...>)             = default;
    attributes(attributes const&) requires contains_v<options::no_copy, opts...> = delete;
    attributes& operator=(attributes const&) requires contains_v<options::no_copy, opts...> =
        delete;
    attributes(attributes&&) requires contains_v<options::no_move, opts...>            = delete;
    attributes& operator=(attributes&&) requires contains_v<options::no_move, opts...> = delete;
};

// Example usage
struct A : attributes<options::no_move, options::no_copy> {
    A() = default;
};
```

Helper trait:

```
template <options opt, options head, options... tail>
struct contains {
    static constexpr bool value{opt == head || contains<opt, tail...>::value};
};

template <options opt, options head>
struct contains<opt, head> {
    static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template <options opt, options... opts>
constexpr bool contains_v{contains<opt, opts...>::value};
```